# Use gitgraph for existing git project

Tags: git, git-log

I want to view my commits on git project graphically, so I downloaded the `GitGraph.js` package from [gitgraphjs.com](https://gitgraphjs.com/).

How can I view my repository graphically using `GitGraph.js`?

Comment: Its not "gitgraph", but I never need any more then just the "graphical" log command line output (which I think is very good) - have you tried: `git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline`. Use the up/down/left/right arrows to navigate it... (the command is a bit of a mouthful, but you can alias it.

Comment: I have seen this but not with all options you gave. Will try this. Thanks for all your suggestions

Answer (score 3):

> Gitgraph.js is a simple JavaScript library which is meant to help you visually presenting git branching stuff like a git workflow, a tricky git command or whatever git tree you'd have in mind.

Which means you cannot use gitgraph to represent an actual repository. It is used just to explain git concepts.

You can try [sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) or other git gui programs.

Comment: Obviously, he *can* use the library to visualize his repository, it's just that he has to write all the code that looks at his repository and calls into the library in the right manner.

Answer (score 0):

I currently am working on a private repository server, on which I implemented this functionality.

As I didn't open-source that project yet, I created a github repository `real-gitgraph` containing the core functionality. It is written in php and uses [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to get commit and tag information.

---

All you have to do is include the `real-gitgraph.php` file and `gitgraph.js`:

```php
<!-- include the tool / library -->
<?php include 'real-gitgraph.php'; ?>

<!-- include gitgraph.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@gitgraph/js"></script>
```

If you want to display the graph for a repository located at `$repoDirectory`, this is what you do:

```html
<!-- Draw the GitGraph -->
<div id="graph-container"></div>
<script><?php echo gitGraphJS($repoDirectory); ?></script>
```

GitHub: [finnmglas/real-gitgraph](https://github.com/finnmglas/real-gitgraph)

---

There still are some [issues](https://github.com/finnmglas/real-gitgraph/issues) with this repository, currently (2020-07-17) it can:

- Graph all commits on the master branch
- Show commit messages and hashes (as tooltips for horizontal graphs)
- Display version tags (see screenshot below)

---

An example git-graph, generated using the included `example.php` script:

[image: an example graph]

*(Note: you can easily customize the graphs design using the template in `real-gitgraph.php`)*

---

*It took me quite a while to get all this set up, if you want to, feel free to [contribute](https://github.com/finnmglas/real-gitgraph) ^^*

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `git log --oneline --graph --all`. This is a very good visualization tool that comes with the git CLI.